# Create Google docs using google docs api (java)

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to make 300 Google docs file.

So i found google docs api but it is not working for me.

It is my source and error.

please help me.

```
// [START docs_quickstart]
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.docs.v1.Docs;
import com.google.api.services.docs.v1.DocsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.docs.v1.model.Document;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DocsQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Docs API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    private static final String DOCUMENT_ID = "195j9eDD3ccgjQRttHhJPymLJUCOUjs-jmwTrekvdjFE";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DocsScopes.DOCUMENTS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DocsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    private static void createDoc(Docs service) throws IOException {
        Document doc = new Document()
                .setTitle("My Document");
        doc = service.documents().create(doc)
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Created document with title: " + doc.getTitle());
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Docs service = new Docs.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Prints the title of the requested doc:
        // https://docs.google.com/document/d/195j9eDD3ccgjQRttHhJPymLJUCOUjs-jmwTrekvdjFE/edit
//        Document response = service.documents().get(DOCUMENT_ID).execute();
//        String title = response.getTitle();
//
//        System.out.printf("The title of the doc is: %s\n", title);
//        
        createDoc(service);


    }
}
// [END docs_quickstart]
```

Error code

```
> Task :run FAILED
3월 13, 2020 3:17:55 오후 com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\work_station\java-samples-master\docs\quickstart\tokens
3월 13, 2020 3:17:55 오후 com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\work_station\java-samples-master\docs\quickstart\tokens
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:451)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1089)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:482)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:599)
        at DocsQuickstart.createDoc(DocsQuickstart.java:79)
        at DocsQuickstart.main(DocsQuickstart.java:97)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

`Private static final list <String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList (DocsScopes).DOCUMENTS);`
I think this line is wrong. Originally, it was `DOCUMENTS_READONLY`, but it did not work and was changed. I'd appreciate it if you could give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are having that error because even if you are using the right scope (`DocsScopes.DOCUMENTS`), you must delete your ***StoredCredential*** file (it's in the tokens folder) in order to refresh the authorization information by doing the Oauth process again and in that way the new scope will be set.

### Notice

You will not be able to create 300 docs in just one run unless you take some precautions because of what the [Docs API Quotas](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits) state:

> - Write requests:
>
>   - 600 per project per 60 seconds
>   - 60 per user per 60 seconds